# Moving WordPress from Root to a subfolder

Tags: installation, domain

I have WordPress set up on my servers www root directory. Now, I would like to also host other content on my server, so I would like to move WordPress to a subfolder like /nameofblog.

However, in the tutorial found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory/), it sounds as if they want to keep the url pointing at the root directory, and thus they set wordpress up to still keep the index.php and some files in the root. I want to change my domain to just have the new folder as it's document root (i have complete access to server and domain). Do i still need to change all this stuff that seems related to having 2 different urls (wordpress address and blog url)? Or can i just copy the files to a subdirectory, make the url point there and I'm good?

Answer (score 1):

Generally when moving a WordPress site  I copy the files to the new path then update the URL in the Dashboad. After logging into the 'new' install and making sure everything looks good I remove the old directory.

Comment: Yes, except that I don't want the URL to point to the old directory. So, I made the URL point to the new subfolder, and I didn't have to change anything in Wordpress. Just copied the files and was good to go.

Answer (score 1):

to move a WordPress site from root to sub folder you first need to copy all the files and folder of WordPress from root folder and then paste it inside sub folder. After doing this you need to change the WordPress address and site address and change it with your sub folder. You can also change these value from your database table. You can find it in the table [prefix]_options. There you will find "siteurl" and "home". Replace it with your sub folder url path.

Comment: You are correct, usually, this would be the way to go. However, I also want to change where the url points, so I dont have to change anything concerning wordpress, because it does not use absolute filepaths anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I did not need to change anything, since the only thing that really changes in this scenario, is the filepath, and wordpress does not use absolute file paths.